# How do I get the object id of an entity during the postRemove event?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have something like this:

```
public function postRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getObject();
    $entity->getId();
}
```

`$entity` has every property from the selected  table except id, which is always `null`

I expect it to have the id of the item that I am removing.

Comment: What kind of ID does the entity have? Autogenerated?

Comment: @yivi Yes. Autogenerated primary key incremental, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you already removed the object, it no longer has an id.

You may want to use `preRemove` where the `id` is still available.

You could even use `preRemove` to store the id in a non-mapped property of the object, and then get that id from the object on `postRemove`.

```php
function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
   $object = $args->getObject();
   $object->storeId($object->getId());
}
```

```
function postRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
   $object = $args->getObject();
   $id     = $object->getStoredId();
}
```

Comment: As of January 2021, this is unfortunately still the only solution. However, this answer requires a setter and getter to be defined in the entity, which I don't like. I outlined a tidier, self-contained solution here: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/2326#issuecomment-754732218

Answer (score 1):

Services are singleton in Symfony. You can use them like a proxy.
Create a property `$objectId` in the listener. Then follow this:

```
function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
   $object = $args->getEntity();
   $this->objectId($object->getId());
}
```

Then in postRemove:

```
function postRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
   $id     = $this->objectId;
}
```